# Solving inequality in Mathematica involving summation

Tags: summation, trigonometry, inequalities

I want to solve the inequality but I can't type it in *Mathematica* and always get an error. It's too complicated for me.

[image]

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: @Feyre I have tried many structures to write it but I'm not able to write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a function `f[n]` returning `True` if the inequality holds, and `False` if not:

```
f[n_] := n - 1 + (n - 1)/4 Sum[Csc[(i - 2) Pi/(n - 1)], {i, 3, n}] < 
  n/4 Sum[Csc[(i - 1) Pi/n], {i, 2, n}]
```

E.g. `f[5]` returns `False`.

```
n = 3;
While[! f[n], n++]
n
```

> 12

i.e. `f[11] === False`, but `f[12] === True`.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you